# zsh - return a value that sometimes ends in $'\n' from a function

Tags: zsh

I've got a zsh function that computes a binary sequence and returns it as a string. Simplified:

```
function make_str() {
   print -n $'\0\1\0\n'
}

myvar="$(make_str "some" "args")"
typeset -p myvar
```

This prints:

```
typeset myvar=$'\C-@\C-A\C-@'
```

So my return value is losing the `\n` at the end, I believe because of the `$()` I use to capture the function's output. From the zsh docs:

> A command enclosed in parentheses preceded by a dollar sign, like ‘$(...)’, or quoted with grave accents, like ‘‘...‘’, is replaced with its standard output, with any trailing newlines deleted.

So, how do I cleanly capture the output of my function in a variable if I can't use command substitution, ie `$()`?

Comment: @muru, yes, thank you. Since I have nulls in my output, some of the options don't work but it looks like the good ol' "add an x at the end" is working.